# Как на лету при вводе дробного числа в input записать целое?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Есть некоторое количество `input.price-all` при вводе в которые дробные цифры должны на лету записываться в `value=""` целыми с увеличением `Math.ceil` не смотря на знак препинания (точка или запятая), но при этом в самом поле они должны оставаться в том виде как их и ввели.
Пример:

В поле: `12,34` или `12.34` в значении `value="13"`

```
<input type="text" class="price-all" value="" />
<input type="text" class="price-all" value="" />
<input type="text" class="price-all" value="" />
<input type="text" class="price-all" value="" />
<input type="text" class="price-all" value="" />
```

Comment: На лету на какой момент? При исчезновении фокуса с поля?
При нажатии Enter? Каждое мгновение? Тогда как вы в принципе введете точку? В любом случае можно попытаться сделать через делегаты (события вообще говоря).

Comment: "при этом в самом поле ..." - значение аттрибута `value` - это и есть то, что Вы видите в "самом поле". Объясните, что Вам на самом деле нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такое решение. Есть событие `oninput`, которое вызывается при любом изменении в поле

```js
$(function() { 
  $('input').on('input', function() {
    var val = $(this).val().replace(/\,/g, '.');
    $(this).attr('value', Math.ceil(val));
  });
  $('button').click(function() {
    alert($('input').attr('value'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
<button>Показать value</button>
```

Comment: Юрий, "значение атрибута value - это и есть то, что Вы видите в "самом поле" ", я это знаю. Но мне важно что бы при отправке формы передавались целые числа. Почему то с приведенным вами примером  работает только первое попавшееся поле, а как быть с остальными?

Comment: В смысле первое попавшееся поле? Это свойство можно применить к любому текстовому input. Почему бы вам при получении значения из input не округлять его перед отправкой, в таком случае?

Comment: Согласен, можно и так, просто в голове была немного другая идея.

Answer (score 0):

Надо на эти инпуты навесить событие (например onfocusout) и там выставлять в value Math.ceil.